# Is this proof is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Could someone please appreciate my attempt at resolution and let me know if I’m doing well?
Is there any other, easier way to demonstrate this question?

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ derivable, such that $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t,x \in \mathbb{R}$ [ $f$ is a Linear transformation]. Prove that $f(x)=f'(0)\cdot x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Proof:

We apply$\:\frac{D^k}{k!}$ in the identity $\:f\left(tx\right)\:=\:t^kf\left(x\right)$, that  is, we derived $k$ times in relation to $t$, applying the chain rule.
$D^kf\left(tx\right)=x^kf^{\left(k\right)}\left(tx\right)\:$ and $\frac{D^k}{k!}t^kf\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$
therefore
$\frac{x^k}{k!}f^k\left(tx\right)=f\left(x\right)$
taking $t=0$ has been 
$\frac{x^k}{k!}f^k\left(0\right)=f\left(x\right).$
In particular if $k = 1, f(x) = x\cdot f'(0)=c\cdot x$.

Thanks!

Comment: If $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t,x$, then $f(x)=xf(1)$. for all $x$.

Comment: @lulu How that ? You apparently set $x=1$ and $t=x$. So, $x$ is not arbitary. And neither is $t$. Or do I miss something ?

Comment: @Peter  If $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all pairs $t,x$  then take $t=x,x=1$ to deduce $f(x\times 1)=x\times f(1)$ for all $x$.  I agree it is a bit awkward to write $t=x,x=1$ so if you prefer let $t=t, x=1$ to write $f(t\times 1)=tf(1)$ for all $t$ and now rename $t$ as $x$.

Comment: @lulu  This way it makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We only know that $f$ is differentiable, not $f'$. Therefore, your proof is not valid.

Instead, we can attempt to find $f'(0)$ directly, using the definition of the derivative:
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0} \, .
$$
Therefore, to find $f'(0)$ we need to find expressions for $f(t)$ and $f(0)$. We are given that $f(tx)=tf(x)$: by setting $x=1$ we find that $f(t)=tf(1)$; by setting $t=0$ we find that $f(0)=0$. Can you finish the proof?